# Converting string to number “Argument isn’t number error”

Tags: perl, parsing

I’m parsing tab delimited files.  Several columns are not being recognizes as numbers even though they are clearly numeric.  When I try to sum up these values errors are display : `Argument ""97"" isn't numeric in addition (+)` and Perl returns 0.

I’ve tried using `Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);` but it produced the same result '0'. Is there something else I can try?

Here is the code:

```
open my $out_fh, '>', $final_variants or die qq{Unable to open "$final_variants" for output: $!};

open my $in_fh, '<', $tsv_file_new
            or die qq{Unable to open "$tsv_file_new" for input: $!};

while ( <$in_fh> ) {

        my @fields = split;

        my $forward_reference = $fields[67];
        my $reverse_reference = $fields[68];
        my $forward_variant_reads = $fields[77];
        my $reverse_variant_reads = $fields[78];

        my $total_reads = (looks_like_number($forward_reference))
                + (looks_like_number($reverse_reference))
                + (looks_like_number($forward_variant_reads))
                + (looks_like_number($reverse_variant_reads));

        my $current_final_line = $headerline . "\t"
                    . $forward_reference . "\t"
                    . $reverse_reference . "\t"
                    . $forward_variant_reads . "\t"
                    . $reverse_variant_reads . "\t"
                    . $total_reads . "\t";

        print $out_fh $current_final_line, "\n";
}
```

Comment: `"97"` does indeed not look like a number, unlike `97`. It sounds like your fields have quotes in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error message already says it: *Argument ""97"" isn't numeric*. This happens when the *number* is actually a string *which is surrounded by quotes (`"`),* like so:

```
my $num = '"42"';
my $sum = $num + 1;
```

This gives:

> Argument ""42"" isn't numeric in addition (+) at...

Try to get rid of the quotes from your *numbers*:

```
$num =~ s/"//g;
```

Comment: As an alternative - pattern match out the numeric component: `my ($num) = $str =~ m/(\d+)/;`

Comment: @Sobrique Far better. Stripping off the quotes like I did is the quick'n'dirty sledge hammer approach.

Answer (score 4):

That error is due to extra quotes, but I'd first mention a coding problem. Adding values by doing `looks_like_number($var) + ...` is an error.
The [looks_like_number](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#looks_like_number), from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html),

> Returns true if perl thinks EXPR is a number.

It is meant for *testing* whether a variable is numeric. It returns either a zero or a large positive integer.  So you need to test first to see which ones are numbers, by filtering by [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for example, and only then use those as numbers.

As explained in the [answer by perlduck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108921/4653379), it is clear that there is extra quoting around. However, I'd be careful with merely removing all quotes as you may expose something which indeed isn't a number. Also, possible quotes *inside* strings may be needed, if other processing is involved.

I would still finally test the variables, cleaned up of enclosing quotes, by `looks_like_number` and assemble those that are numeric.  Perhaps

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
# Remove extra (leading and trailing) quotes, for example
my @references   = map { s/^"//; s/"$//; $_ } ($forward_reference, ...);
my @numeric_refs = grep { looks_like_number($_) } @references;
my $total_reads  = sum @numeric_refs;
```

Here `sum` from the core [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module is used.  All of the above can be strung in one statement, if nothing other than summing is done (so there is no good use of those intermediate arrays), since each operation takes and returns a list

```
my $total_reads  = sum
    grep { looks_like_number($_) }
    map { s/^"//; s/"$//; $_ } $forward_reference, ...;
```

---

Better yet, you can parse tab-delimited files with [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emakamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm), which handles quotes very nicely.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( 
    { binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", allow_loose_quotes => 1 } 
) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag ();

my $file = $tsv_file_new;
open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my @fields = @$row;
    # process. quotes around fields are gone
    # ...
    my @references = ($forward_reference, ...);
    my $total_reads = sum grep { looks_like_number($_) } @references;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```